# Sequelize Query returning strange models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I make a query using sequelize, such as this

```
let User  = require('../models').User;
...
User.findOne({ where:{ email :  email }}).then( user => {
    console.log(user);
})
```

The user object returned there looks very strange and has some negative side effects. It looks like this (linking because too long):

https://pastebin.com/HLVHVetN

So I can't do things like user.email or user.instanceMethod as many examples show. Even worse, when I attempt to call an instance method, `this` references the function, not the model.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is how my User model looks

```
'use strict';
let Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {


let User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100), allowNull: true, unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: {
                msg: 'No es una dirección de correo electrónico.'
            },
        }
    },
    google_id: {type: Sequelize.STRING(100)},

    facebook_id: {type: Sequelize.STRING(100)},
    password_digest: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        allowNull: true,
        validate: {
            len: [6, Infinity]
        }
    },
    password_confirmation: {
        type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL
    },

    token_reset: {type: Sequelize.STRING(100)},
    token_confirm: {type: Sequelize.STRING(100)},
    browser_key: {type: Sequelize.STRING(100)},
    registry_ip: {type: Sequelize.STRING(60)},
    registry_date: {type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW},
    account_confirmed: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false},
    terms_accepted: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false}, 
    account_active: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true},
    current_ip: {type: Sequelize.STRING(60)},
    login_date: {type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW}
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ['email']}],
    instanceMethods: {
        authenticate: function (value) {
            console.log("THIS",this);
            console.log("comparing passwords",value, this.password_digest);
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(value, this.password_digest))
                return this;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside sequelize promise you will get properties from dataValues. so if you want to access in same thenable promise use
`User.dataValues.email`
and definately this will point to sequelize object 
you need to return the values and use in other function if you don't want to use that promise. 
other way around is to use `raw:true`

```
User.findOne({raw:true,  where:{ email :  email }}).then( user => {
    console.log(user);
})
```

Comment: Yeah but is this normal? It doesn't look like what documentation says I should be getting. Plus, I can't seem to use the instance methods properly like this, because the "this" reference is off.

Comment: Oh nice! That does get me the attributes. Though still not getting the instance functions.